# Composer update failed: "C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar" could not be written

Tags: windows, composer-php

While installing Laravel 10x I receive the following error:

```
 Problem 1
    - laravel/framework[v10.10.0, ..., v10.13.5] require composer-runtime-api ^2.2 -> found composer-runtime-api[2.0.0] but it does not match the constraint.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^10.10 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v10.10.0, ..., v10.13.5].
```

Then I proceeded to try to update the composer with the command `composer selfupdate`, but got the error:

```
 [Composer\Downloader\FilesystemException]
  Filesystem exception:
  Composer update failed: "C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar" could not be written.
  rename(C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin/composer-temp.phar,C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar): Access is denied (code: 5)
```

What have I done to try to solve the problem:

1. Opened VSCode as Administrator
2. Open & run the command in CMD as Administrator
3. Open & run the command in Powershell as Administrator
4. Open the properties of the folder `ComposerSetup` and removed `Read only` option

None of the above options worked. How do I solve  this?

Comment: How did you install Composer on that system? Have you tried re-installing it? (that is uninstall the current version, install the latest the same way of how you installed the previous). And don't know if it's the same today, but traditionally Windows loves reboots.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error while trying to update Composer with `self-update`, and fixed the issue by deleting the existing `composer.phar` file and renaming manually `composer-temp.phar` (the file created by the `self-update` command) to `composer.phar`.

Answer (score -1):

in my case, I had the same problem. I wanted to execute the

```
composer install
```

command and Install packages. but I faced several errors. and one of them was your problem as well. another one was `laravel/framework[v10.0.0, ..., v10.0.3] require composer-runtime-api ^2.2 -> found composer-runtime-api[2.1.0] but it does not match the constraint` . The solution for this problem in Stackoverflow was to run these commands:

```
composer clearcache

composer selfupdate
```

but when I executed the second command I had errors as well. **Finally, I downloaded Latest Composer from the [official website](https://getcomposer.org/) and installed it manually on my system(Windows OS). then all the problems were gone.**

**note:** *I knew that my problem was with the version and wanted to update the composer via the command line and the methods other developers suggested. But I've done it by download and install manually.*